# RestSharp Deserialize JSON Dictionary

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, restsharp

I'm having some trouble using RestSharp to deserialize a JSON response from a REST service, but I suspect this would happen with Newtonsoft or other libraries, it's a serialization thing rather than a library-specific thing.

The response is part dictionary/collection, part response code, but the dictionary/collection elements aren't presented as an array, but items with a numeric property name.

```
{ "StatusCode": 1, "1": { forename: "Test", surname: "Subject", addressLine1: "1 The Street" }, "2": { ... }, "3": { ... } ... }
```

I'm trying to deserialize this to a POCO, but I'm not sure how to go about deserializing those numbered items.  Has anyone done this before, or know how I can do this?  I'm not precious about the POCO, anything that works is fine.

```
public class ServiceResponse
{
    public int StatusCode { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<int, ServiceResponseItem> Items { get; set; }
}

public class ServiceResponseItem 
{
    public string Forename { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Share sample JSON as well?

Comment: @FaizanRabbani the data itself is sensitive, and i get this on a number of different services from the same provider, however, I'm updating the question to show a structure that I've tested with, and the corresponding POCOs I'm using.

Comment: Is data inside "1": { ... } same or is it different as well?

Comment: Identical for each instance.  It's multiple hits on a service to search people.  Each hit is a person.  Same schema/properties per person, but multiple instances.

Comment: Well if I try to paste special on Visual Studio it generates POCO as following:

public class Rootobject
    {
        public int StatusCode { get; set; }
        public _1 _1 { get; set; }
    }

    public class _1
    {
        public string forename { get; set; }
        public string surname { get; set; }
        public string addressLine1 { get; set; }
    }

Comment: That's precisely the problem.  I can't base a collection of variable size on properties called '1', or '2' as your pasted example shows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have achieved it by the following code:

```
dynamic res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(
                "{ \"StatusCode\": 1, \"1\": { \"forename\": \"Test\", \"surname\": \"Subject\", \"addressLine1\": \"1 The Street\" }}");
            IDictionary<string, JToken> datas = res;
            foreach (var dt in datas.Skip(1))
            {
                Info newInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Info>(dt.Value.ToString());
            }


public class StackOverFlow
    {
        public int StatusCode { get; set; }
        public Info Info { get; set; }
    }

    public class Info
    {
        public string forename { get; set; }
        public string surname { get; set; }
        public string addressLine1 { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Definitely looks like my best bet so far, but for some reason my result isn't able to cast to IDictionary<string, JToken> as you've done.  I'll do some digging around that though.  Definitely given me a lead to work with.

Comment: @ChrisDisley please let me know if you face problem, I can help.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually managed to resolve this using the following (the type that came back was a JObject which is why it wouldn't cast to IDictionary per the @FaizanRabbani answer.

```
public StackOverflow Parse(string json)
{
    StackOverflow response = new StackOverflow();
    response.Items = new List<Info>();

    dynamic res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
    response.StatusCode = res.StatusCode;

    foreach (JProperty item in res)
    {

        if (item.Name != "StatusCode")
        {
            var infoItem = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Info>(item.Value.ToString());
            response.Items.Add(infoItem);
        }
    }


    return response;
}
```